# Images not being loaded and pushed into array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops

I wanted to make a short cut for writing all the onload functions for my images by looping through an object's variables called `GameImages`. I'm not sure why the images aren't being loaded when I look in the developer console in chrome. Is the for loop interrupting the loading of the images? How can I load the images in a loop instead of writing each onload function?

```
var i = 1; //set increment variable

var GameImages = { //object to hold each image

    game1 : new Image(),
    game2 : new Image(),
    game3 : new Image(),
    game4 : new Image(),
    game5 : new Image(),

};

for(gameImage in GameImages) { //loop through each image

    gameImage.onload = function () { //set the onload function for the current image

        gamePosters.push(gameImage);
        console.log(gamePosters.length); //print out the new size of the gamePosters array

    };

    //give source of image. (my images are named game1.jpg, game2.jpg, etc.)
    gameImage.src = "images/assets/posters/games/game" + i + ".jpg";

    i += 1; //increment i
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're `for (gameImage in GameImages)` loop is looping through each of your GameImage object's properties (i.e. gameImage is first "game1", then "game2", etc.). Change your code to:

```
for (game in GameImages) {

   var gameImage = GameImages[game]; // This will get your actual Image
   gameImage.onload = function () { 

       gamePosters.push(gameImage);
       console.log(gamePosters.length); 

   };

   //give source of image. (my images are named game1.jpg, game2.jpg, etc.)
   gameImage.src = "images/assets/posters/games/game" + i + ".jpg";

   i += 1; //increment i
}
```